# Access temp-table "Label" attribute in Progress Openedge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm looking for a way to access the table `LABEL` value "Customer Information" from the following temp-table definition:

```
/* Define the temp-table */
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCustomer LABEL "Customer Information"
    FIELD CustNum AS INTEGER
    FIELD CustName AS CHARACTER
    FIELD CustCity AS CHARACTER.

/* Access the label attribute */
DISPLAY ttCustomer:LABEL.
```

I've tried various flavors of the above and can't figure out the magic combo.

Comment: Why do you want to find the LABEL? Maybe using the tt name helps? ````DISPLAY TEMP-TABLE ttCustomer:NAME.````

Comment: It's confusing and IMHO wrong, that the compiler accepts a LABEL phrase there. The LABEL is part of the field-options and should only be valid after the FIELD keyword. Peter's and Tom's answer below show how to retrieve the field-label at runtime.

Comment: @RaphaelFrei Using the label as a bit of a hack in an auto-exporter of arbitrary temp-tables from Progress to XLSX.  (the temp-table labels become the human-readable sheet name)

Comment: @slumtrimpet In that case maybe use ``serialize-name`` which can be set and read normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the [documentation](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/DEFINE-TEMP-TABLE-statement.html) does not indicate that a label can be defined, a temp-table can be given a label which **is** used in error messages. Which provides an opening to extracting the label:

```
define temp-table tt label 'ttbar'
    field ii as int
    .

find tt where false.

catch e as progress.lang.error:

    message entry( 2, e:getMessage(1), ' ' ).

end catch.
```

Comment: That is clever.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I’m just not sure if the Progress error messages are formatted with table label first in all languages.

Answer (score 3):

The temp-table itself doesn't have a LABEL but the individual fields do. You can access them like so:

```
DISPLAY buffer ttCustomer:buffer-field( "custName" ):LABEL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Stefan's amazing idea, this is the actual solution implemented for the original question (with a space in the table label) and working on ancient versions of Progress as well as current iterations:

```
def var err as char.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCustomer LABEL "Customer Information"
  FIELD CustNum AS INTEGER
  FIELD CustName AS CHARACTER
  FIELD CustCity AS CHARACTER.

find ttCustomer where false no-error.
/* ** [tt label or name] record not on file. (138) */
err = substring(error-status:get-message(1), 4).
message substring(err, 1, length(err) - length(' record not on file. (138)')).
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for missing the space. Be sure not to try this with Progress installed in a language other than (American) English, you could use a reference temp-table with a unique label to identify the error message structure.